# Saying Tanach by Heart

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tanach, see-sight-vision-blind, writing-printing

> מִזְמוֹרֵי תְהִלִּים וְכֵן שְׁאָר 
>   פָּרָשִׁיּוֹת מִתּוֹרָה נְבִיאִים וּכְתוּבִים
>   שֶׁאֵינָם שְׁגוּרִים בְּפִי הַכֹּל, אָסוּר 
>   לְאָמְרָם בְּעַל פֶּה. אֲפִלּוּ מִי שֶׁהוּא 
>   יוֹדֵעַ לְאָמְרָם בְּעַל פֶּה, יֶשׁ לוֹ 
>   לִזָּהֵר שֶׁלֹּא לְאָמְרָם בְּעַל פֶּה. 
>   וְסוּמָא מֻתָּר

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 1:6

According to this law, one cannot say a section from Tanach without the text unless it is something that people often say by heart. What falls under this category? For example, would the portion of the Torah (the commandment for the Kohanim to bless the Children of Israel) that follows the Blessing on the Torah count as something we often say by heart? What about Shema?

Comment: It presumably varies with time and place. If so, there isnt really a definitive answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the words of the Shulchan Aruch (OC 49:1),

> אף על גב דקיימא לן דברים שבכתב אי אתה רשאי לאומרם על פה כל דבר שרגיל ושגור בפי הכל כגון קריאת שמע וברכת כהנים ופרשת התמיד וכיוצא בהן מותר

So Shema and the blessings of the kohanim are OK to say by heart since "everyone is fluent in them".  Many poskim discuss what is considered "everyone is fluent in", and many other leniencies that apply here as well. See [here](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Dvarim_SheBichtav) for examples and sources.

Comment: the shulchan aruch's examples are clearly outdated as 90% of religious Jews (myself excluded) probably don't say parashat hatamid daily.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wouldn't say 90% because most Sefaradim do.

Comment: @DoubleAA, (to add to HachamGabriel's comment,) _chasidim_ do, too.

Comment: @msh210 , HachamGabriel : I recognize that others have it more prominently in the siddur, but I wonder whether all of them actually say it regularly. (It's in the artscroll ashkenaz siddurim too, but I'm afraid that hasn't motivated too many people to say it.) Also, most shuls in Israel (of whatever variety) start from Hodu/Baruch Sheamar and half of Jews live there. Maybe 90% is a little exaggerated, but it's much higher than the Shulchan Aruch was expecting.

Answer (score 3):

R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi writes in [Likkutei Torah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14963&st=&pgnum=89) that in order to cleave to Hashem constantly, one should learn all of Chumash by heart.

---

Moreover, the [Hayom Yom](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/hayomyom.asp?tDate=3/26/2012) says that

> Among my father's regular Torah-study sessions: A parsha of Chumash with Rashi daily; **reciting Tanach by heart** - a chapter each of Torah, Nevi'im and Ketuvim; a chapter of Mishnayot; a regular session in profound study of Gemara - two folio pages weekly, another in rapid study of Gemara - three pages daily; a session of study of the Jerusalem Talmud; a regular period for Codes, but not daily. During the course of the year he would conclude the entire Midrash Raba, "borrowing" from the long sedrot and "repaying" on the shorter ones

Emphasis mine.

Comment: And say it by heart?

Comment: @msh210: he doesn't mention that.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add an opinion to the many valid ones that were already presented, the GR"A [(quoted in Mishnah Berura 49:6)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=154) holds that this prohibition only applies when you are being *motzi* other people.

Comment: Indeed, and this does seem to be the majority opinion among rishonim.

Comment: What is a case where you’re being motzi someone with a passage of Tanach?

Comment: @DonielF Shabbos Kiddush. Megillat Esther. Torah reading in general (which is the case of the Gemara) and arguably Haftarah as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this answers the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA May I note that your mention of Shabbos Kiddush [doesn’t apply to daytime Kiddush](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11008/9682), but otherwise I’ll accept that.

Comment: @DonielF It applies to both in communities that customary say verses at both and to neither in communities that don't.

Comment: @DoubleAA The chiyuv is the bracha, not the pesukim

Comment: @DonielF Certainly, both at night and during the day. But, assuming you're from a community that customarily says verses then, why don't you say the Pesukim also while the Mekaddesh is? Is it not because of Shomea keOneh?

Answer (score 2):

According to Rabbenu Hayyim Paltiel (Numbers 28:9) verses cited in prayer on Shabbat or even Rosh Hodesh are sufficiently frequent to not have the problem. Verses cited only on the holidays, are sufficiently rare to have the problem. As examples of frequently cited verses which may be recited be mentions Sh'ma and Az Yashir.

According to the Bach (OH 49:1) any text very familiar to an individual may be recited by that individual, regardless of whether it is popularly known.